# Custom DayView in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to custom a `MonthListView` extending from `LinearLayout` (list of months), each month has  about 30 `DayView`s extending from `ConstraintLayout` (`DayView` is also my custom view), each `DayView` has 5 child views. When I open CalendarScreen with a MonthListView inside, the screen opens slowly. I find out the problem is calling `findViewById` too much, example, if my MonthListView contains 1 month, it will call `findViewById()` method 1*30*5 (150) times (1 month, 30 days and 5 child views in each dayView). I know that `findViewById()` is heavy computational method so it make UI slow down.

```
public class DayView extends ConstraintLayout {
    //attributes declarations

    public DayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflateLayout(context);
        mTextViewDay = findViewById(R.id.textViewDay);
        mTextViewPrice = findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
        mViewBackground = findViewById(R.id.viewDayBg);
        mImageViewShape = findViewById(R.id.imageViewDayShape);
        mImageViewThunder = findViewById(R.id.imageViewThunder);
    }

    protected void inflateLayout(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_day, this);
    }
}
```

The snippet code below illustrate my implementation for a DayView. I did map child views by calling `findViewById` from constructor. Can you help me to find another way to implement dayView with faster opening speed? I am so appreciate your responds! Thanks all!

Comment: can you share the screenshot or design exactly how you want the design

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology Thank for your attention this is my screen. https://imgur.com/a/XuF0Dkr

Comment: It's monthly view of calender not daily view

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology DayViews are cells inside the monthView. you want my XML file?

Comment: You can refer this link to make customized cells 

https://medium.com/meetu-engineering/create-your-custom-calendar-view-10ff41f39bfe

also check this :

https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Comment: Thank you, I have refered the link bofore, their DayView just contains one view (a textview for show number), mine contains 5 views. So I must trade off between UI and speed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200690/discussion-between-silversky-technology-and-ta-quang-tu).

Comment: Ok @SilverskyTechnology. I am so appreciate!